# Create user account using REST api or xml rpc in mongooseim as it do in ejabberd

Tags: erlang, ejabberd, mongoose-im

I am trying to create user account in mongooseim server using rest interface.
I am not sure about this rest interface described here https://mongooseim.readthedocs.io/en/latest/developers-guide/REST-interface-to-metrics/

I can create account and do many things in ejabberd using XML RPC.

Is there any way to do it in mongooseim server?

Comment: XML RPC is not supported in MongooseIM. You can create users using `mongooseimctl` command line interface or directly using XMPP (when `mod_register` module is enabled on the server).

Comment: I need rest api to do some other tasks also, which is already supported in ejabberd.

Answer (score 0):

I can do most of things on command line using mod_admin_extra , and I can build a simple interface for my application over it .

Here is  mod_admin_extra docs, 
http://mongooseim.readthedocs.io/en/1.6.1/modules/mod_admin_extra/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [HTTP Administration API](https://mongooseim.readthedocs.io/en/latest/http-api/http-administration-api-documentation/).